How do I determine if a class's name exists as a key in a mapped object type?
I have a type that I'm trying to make dynamic. I currently have a hardcoded version that looks like this:
import type {
  Text,
  TextOptions,
} from 'pixi.js'

export type ConstructorParams<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> =
  T extends typeof Text
    ? TextOptions
    : T extends new (...args: infer A) => any
      ? A[0]
      : never;

The goal is to return TextOptions if T matches typeof Text, otherwise return the first parameter of the constructor as long as it's also a class. That works fine, but now I want to be able to match multiple types here without writing a bunch of individual conditionals. This is what I've got so far (non-functional):
import type {
  BlurFilter,
  BlurFilterOptions,
  Text,
  TextOptions,
} from 'pixi.js'

type ConstructorOverrides = {
  BlurFilter: BlurFilterOptions
  Text: TextOptions
}

export type ConstructorParams<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> =
  T extends keyof ConstructorOverrides
    ? ConstructorOverrides[T]
    : T extends new (...args: infer A) => any
      ? A[0]
      : never;

This new type is intended to achieve the same goal as the original type, except based off of a dictionary of classes instead of a single class. If T is Text, we should still return TextOptions, but if T is BlurFilter, we should return BlurFilterOptions. If T is neither of those, we should return the first parameter of the constructor so long as that parameter has a constructor.
Of course the second version doesn't work because it's checking if T matches a union type of the keys in ConstructorOverrides, but it needs to be checking if the type of T exists within the union type. I've been smashing my head on it all morning... how can I update this type to achieve my goals?

• Empty classes make poor examples. Please [edit] to give them some structural difference, such as in this playground. • Class names don't exist in the type system. You could manually assign them string literal types like this playground, or you could not try to use keys to look it up, like this playground. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate source; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz The last playground you linked gets me really close, but we're just short of the actual solution. I've updated the question to better reflect one of the original constraints I had missed. This playground Has an implementation of that solution, but once I put the Extract line into another conditional I end up with just a union type. I'm not sure I even grok why that is.

Instead of using a mapped type, this can be accomplished using a set of tuples to map out the overrides.
type ConstructorOverrides =
  | [typeof BlurFilter, BlurFilterOptions]
  | [typeof Text, TextOptions]

Then we can use Extract<> to retrieve and check the appropriate keys.
type ConstructorOptions<T extends abstract new (...args: any[]) => any> =
  Extract<ConstructorOverrides, { 0: T }> extends [T, infer R]
    ? R
    : never;

Finally we can add an unknown check to handle fallbacks outside of the overrides:
type ConstructorOptions<T extends abstract new (...args: any[]) => any> =
  Extract<ConstructorOverrides, { 0: T }> extends [T, infer R]
    ? unknown extends R
      ? ConstructorParameters<T>[0]
      : R
    : never;

Notes
Extract<> resolves to unknown if it doesn't find a match, which means it can always resolve. We need an extra check to determine whether R is unknown, otherwise any type that doesn't exist in our overrides will always resolve to unknown.
Additionally, the order of unknown extends R is important. Because unknown is the top type, it's the resolved type if it matches R. This allows us to fall through to R as long as R doesn't match unknown. If R does match unknown, we'll use the fallback instead. If the order is flipped (R extends unknown), the conditional never resolves appropriately and ends up falling through to never in all cases.
Playground
Check out the final solution on TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wRVz5w
Credits
Thanks to @jcalz for turning me towards Extract<> and tuples over mapped types.
Thanks to @/Burrito on the Typescript Discord for helping me understand how to achieve the fallback control flow I wanted.
